# Proving convergence of a sequence $(y_n)$ under certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Suppose  $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence and $(y_n)$ satisfies the following condition:

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\ m\in \mathbb N:|x_n-y_n|<\epsilon\ \forall\ n\geq m$

Prove that the sequence $(y_n)$ is convergent.

***I KNOW THAT THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ASKED BEFORE [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263466/if-x-n-is-a-convergent-sequence-for-any-epsilon0-exists-m-such-that)*** but I want to verify my method which again is a bit long.

***My approach***:

Let $\lim(x_n)=L$, therefore $\forall\ \epsilon>0, \exists\ k\in \mathbb N:|x_n-L|<\epsilon\ \forall\ n\geq k$

$$\text{We have}\ \forall\ \epsilon>0, \exists\ m\in \mathbb N:|x_n-y_n|<\epsilon\ \forall\ n\geq m$$

Let $\epsilon = |x_n-L|$ and $r=\sup\{m,k\}$.

$$\therefore |x_n-y_n|<|x_n-L|\space\forall\ n\geq r$$

Thus $(x_n-y_n)^2<(x_n-L)^2$
$$y_n^2-2x_ny_n<L^2-2x_nL$$
$$(y_n-L)(y_n+L)<2x_n(y_n-L)$$
Suppose $y_n<L\space \forall\ n\geq r$, this implies that $(y_n)$ must be convergent.

Suppose $y_n>L \space \forall\ n\geq r$, then $y_n<y_n+L<2x_n\space \forall\ n\geq r$

Now since $x_n$ is convergent, therefore $(y_n)$ must be convergent.

If $y_n=L$, then it would yield in  a constant sequence which again, is convergent.

$\therefore $ The sequence $(y_n)$ is convergent in all cases.

Please help me verify this method. Any correction would be highly appreciated

***Thanks***

Comment: Your definition of $\epsilon$ is flawed, because it depends on $n$. It is not allowed to depend on it. Your solution does not work.

Comment: @MushuNrek, I'm sorry but I don't understand how does $\epsilon$ depends on $n$ here.

Comment: you have defined $\epsilon = \vert x_n - L\vert$. So $\epsilon$ depends on $n$ through $x_n$.

Comment: You have not shown the statement for *all* $\epsilon$, but only for those of the form $\epsilon = |x_n-L|$ for some $n$.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон and then the $n$ is taken to the limit simultanuously with other terms. There is more than one problem in this proof

Comment: @MushuNrek True, was pointing out the first one I saw : not the last , it seems!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You can write these errors in the answer so that I may accept it.